# Rate of convergence to find root of $x^2-5$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

I want to find out the rate of convergence to find the root of $f(x)=x^2-5$ using fixed point iteration with

\begin{align}
x_k = \Phi(x_{k-1}) &&&&&&\Phi(x)=1+x-x^2/5
\end{align}

I already know that it converges linearly, so I have to find $q \in (0,1)$ such that

\begin{align}
\lim_{k \to \infty} \left\lvert \frac{x_j-x^*}{x_{j-1}-x^*} \right\rvert = q
\end{align}

where $x^* := \lim_{k \to \infty} \Phi(x_k)$

So I can plug in

\begin{align}
\lim_{k \to \infty} \left\lvert \frac{1+x_{j-1}-x_{j-1}^2/5 - x^*}{1+x_{j-2}-x_{j-2}^2/5 - x^*} \right\rvert
\end{align}

But how do I find $q$ now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not write $x_{j-1}-x^\ast$ as $\Phi(x_{j-2}) - x^\ast$, you should let that as it stands. Then you get the quotient

$$\left\lvert \frac{x_j-x^\ast}{x_{j-1}-x^\ast}\right\rvert = \left\lvert \frac{1 - x_{j-1}^2/5 + x_{j-1}-x^\ast}{x_{j-1}-x^\ast}\right\rvert = \left\lvert 1-\frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{x_{j-1}^2-5}{x_{j-1}-x^\ast}\right\rvert.$$

Now take a close look at the last fraction. What was $x^\ast$ again?